# Run 64Bit Ubuntu on virtualbox guest

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have ubuntu 16.04 64Bit Host with virtualbox installed. Virtualization has been enabled so I could create an ubuntu 16.04 64Bit guest successfully and start it.
Now I would like to create a new Ubuntu 64Bit box on the **guest** but I am not able to do it apparently because virtualization is disabled (even if I enabled the VTx setting in virtual box).
Is there any workaround? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its a recurring question but cannot find a good post.

I can find a good answer on quora https://www.quora.com/VirtualBox-inside-VirtualBox-Is-that-possible/answer/Senthil-Nathan-19

**tldr;**

*You can run 32-bit operating systems nested, but not 64*

and here the long story

> This is a fun topic/project to think about and mostly people wonder
>   why this is important or what purpose it serves.  Understanding if
>   this is possible and why if not, helps us understand virtualization
>   better.  For VirtualBox itself the answer to this is “yes” for running
>   32-bit nested guests and “no” for 64-bit.  VirtualBox does NOT have
>   the code for running 64-bit VMs without CPU Extensions (AMD-V, Intel
>   VT-x).  So the inner VM that is running on a host VM will not be able
>   to support 64-bit. The parent/host (which is a guest VM) will not have
>   the CPU extension feature. Supposedly VMware and Xen support soft
>   coding the CPU extensions. And then there are possibilities of
>   crossing virtualization technologies such as starting Xen inside
>   VirtualBox, etc.
>
> The Intel Haswell CPU has a new virtualization technology called
>   Virtual Machine Control Structure (VMCS) Shadowing. VMCS shadowing,
>   accelerates nested virtualization allowing guests to run with minimal
>   impact. VMCS may become mainstream once all virtualization
>   technologies start to implement it. VMCS allows you to run multiple
>   hypervisors on one CPU natively. If there is a need to create nested
>   VMs (or many VMs), consider running container based VMs such as Linux
>   Containers or OpenVZ.  Containers should typically run inside another
>   VM without any issues.