# Minikube 32 bit installation issue in ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, 32-bit, minikube

I am unable to install 32 bit minikube on ubuntu 18.04. Now just need a solution can I somehow install 32 minikube insde my GUEST so that i can run it. Because right now I can't dual boot my HOST. Although dual booting will ultimately solve my problem I know. Can i enable GUEST virtualization  by tweaking settings of HOST virtualbox.

Senario

```
HOST [windows 7 64-bit]
GUEST [ ubuntu 18.04 64-bit]
```

Steps followed

```
1. Installed 64 bit virtual box inside my HOST. 
2. Installed GUEST in Virtual box ( in HOST as a vm ).
3. Installed Virutal box inside my GUEST (virtual box only shows 32-bit os due to inside vm nested virtualization not supported AFAIK ). 
4. installed kubectl in GUEST.
5. Downloaded minikube for GUEST  (but downloaded 64-bit minikube [LINK](https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64) 
 because did not found 32 bit image. I do know it will not work because it is 64-bit which will not work on 32-bit architecture in my case).
```

```sh
start minikube
```

below are logs after running above command in GUEST

```
* minikube v1.2.0 on linux (amd64)
* Downloading Minikube ISO ...
 129.33 MB / 129.33 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
E0702 00:59:42.328274    7241 start.go:559] StartHost: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

X Unable to start VM
* Error:         [VBOX_VTX_DISABLED] create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Advice:        In some environments, this message is incorrect. Try 'minikube start --no-vtx-check'
* Related issues:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900

* If the above advice does not help, please let us know:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new
```

Comment: Can I move my this question to stack exchange network or what should I do now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is link for solution which I was search Tried just today with latest tools description below [SOLUTION LINK](https://medium.com/@vovaprivalov/setup-minikube-on-virtualbox-7cba363ca3bc)

`minikube version`

minikube version: v1.2.0

`kubectl version`

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.1", GitCommit:"4485c6f18cee9a5d3c3b4e523bd27972b1b53892", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-18T09:18:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:32:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: RELATED ONES ARE [LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294304/minikube-install-in-ubuntu-vm-vt-x-amd-v-enabling-to-vm-inside-another-vm) But did know why my question was down voted .

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Virtual extensions in your BIOS. Reboot your computer, go into the BIOS settings (usually you will need to hit a specific hey like Delete or F2 or something for this to happen), then enable the extensions.

Comment: As per my above scenario. GUEST is 64-bit but nested virtualization is not supported. Just like  HOST (virtual box ) --> VM (Virtual box) --> VM (only can be 32 bit Can't be 64 bit ) as per my current knowledge. This nested support for virtualization is not configurable in virtual box. Here is relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003416/run-64bit-ubuntu-on-virtualbox-guest?rq=1)

Comment: There is a problem with nested virtualization inside virtualbox. You can run: 
`minikube start --vm-driver=none` 
Please refer to Specifying the [VM driver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/#specifying-the-vm-driver) none - `Runs the Kubernetes components on the host and not in a VM. Using this driver requires Docker (docker install) and a Linux environment`